# What is a word for "slightly smile with embarrassment"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for "slightly smile with embarrassment"?

Example:

> "You look great tonight," I said.  She ______ed, trying to hide her
>   face from me.

Answer (score 4):

Although it isn't a smile, the word ***[blush](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blush)*** works perfectly here:

> To become red in the face, especially from modesty, embarrassment, or shame; flush.
>
> *"You look great tonight," I said. She **blushed**, trying to hide her face from me.*

[TFD]

Comment: Blushing is completely different from smiling with embarrasment. They may often happen in concert, but one does not require the other.

Comment: Nothing said implied that they did require each other. And I fail to see how they are "completely different." They are both things done in embarrassment.

Comment: They do not mean the same thing. It's as if someone had asked for "a word for eating noodles" and you said "slurping". It is possible to eat noodles without slurping, and it is possible to be embarrassed without blushing.

Answer (score 3):

> "You look great tonight," I said. She **smiled, bashfully**, trying to hide her face from me.

If you can get that down to one word be my guest.  But I say a bashful smile is closest to what you want.